# Temp Data And session in null on the post method (Second Method ) Asp.net core web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I, am trying to use TempData in ASP.NET core on second httppost method the TempData value is null. I have done lots of research but not able to solve the issue I, am facing the null value in the TempData and session

Here is the **project.json** file

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0"
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>(); 
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Market.cs**

```
[HttpGet("{pageNumber}")]
public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> GetMarketList(int pageNumber)
{
    TempData["Currentpage"] = pageNumber; --> value is set here
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Currentpage", pageNumber);
    return genericResponseObject;
}

[HttpPost]
public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> AddUpdateMarket([FromBody] MarketViewModel marketViewModel)
{
    GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> genericResponseObject = new GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>>();
    genericResponseObject.IsSuccess = false;
    string name = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Currentpage"); --> the value is null here
    genericResponseObject = GetMarketList(Convert.ToInt16(TempData.Peek("Currentpage")));
    return genericResponseObject;
}
```

This is the first method to hold the data
[image: First Method]

[image: This is the second method]

The Second method in which Temp Data and session is null

Comment: Do you read your Temp Data in your view?

Comment: No. I am reading in the second http call that is "public GenericResponseObject<List<MarketViewModel>> AddUpdateMarket([FromBody] MarketViewModel marketViewModel)"

Comment: Why storing both on TempData and Session? Have you tried using only TempData?

Comment: Yes I, tried tempData only. It is not working

Comment: I also have the same issue. Has anyone suggestion for this?

Comment: I know this is old, but how is this fixed?